# Create dictionary using dictionary comprehension and assign multiple values to each key

Tags: python-3.x

Need to turn a list of words into a dictionary using dictionary comprehension. The keys would be the length of the words, and the values are the set of words from the original list whose length are that of its keys.

I am able to create a regular function for this purpose, but unable to do so in one dictionary comprehension.

As an example, I created a list of names of different lengths.

```
word_list = ["Amber", "Steven", "Carol", "Tuan", "Michael", "sam", "Wayne", "Anna", "Kay", "Jim", "D", "Belinda", "CharlieYu"]

def word_lengths_notit(input_list):
    wl_dict = {}
    for word in input_list:
        if len(word) not in wl_dict.keys():
            wl_dict[len(word)]=[] #create key that is the length of the word
            wl_dict[len(word)].append(word.lower())
        else:
            if word.lower() not in wl_dict[len(word)]:
                wl_dict[len(word)].append(word.lower())
    print(wl_dict)


word_lengths_notit(word_list)  

My output:
{5: ['amber', 'carol', 'wayne'], 6: ['steven'], 4: ['tuan', 'anna'], 7: ['michael', 'belinda'], 3: ['sam', 'kay', 'jim'], 1: ['d'], 9: ['charlieyu']}
```

This might not be the cleanest/most efficient code (I just started learning two weeks ago), but the output is correct.

Below, I tried dictionary comprehension, but it keeps overwriting my previous values instead of appending to it. I'm thinking I might have to use a list comprehension to collect all the words of the same length, but I'm not sure how (or if I can) create multiple lists of words of different lengths in one list comprehension.

```
def word_lengths(input_list):
    wl_dict = {len(word):word for word in input_list]

    print(wl_dict)


word_lengths(word_list)  

Output: {5: 'Wayne', 6: 'Steven', 4: 'Anna', 7: 'Belinda', 3: 'Jim', 1: 'D', 9: 'CharlieYu'}
```

Answer (score 1):

So you're looking to make a `dict` where each key is an integer and each value is a list, and you're looking to do it via dict comprehension. My advice for doing it in vanilla python is to simply nest a list comprehension (to filter words by name) inside of the dict comprehension:

```
word_list = ["Amber", "Steven", "Carol", "Tuan", "Michael", "sam", "Wayne", "Anna", "Kay", "Jim", "D", "Belinda", "CharlieYu"]
word_lengths = {n: [word for word in word_list if len(word) == n] 
                   for n in range(10)}
```

If you want to avoid cases like `0: []`, you could throw a ternary if clause on the end there to filter them out (e.g. `if len([word for word in word_list if len(word) == n])`). Alternatively, you could simply make a set of all the unique lengths that are present and iterate over that:

```
word_list = ["Amber", "Steven", "Carol", "Tuan", "Michael", "sam", "Wayne", "Anna", "Kay", "Jim", "D", "Belinda", "CharlieYu"]
possible_lengths = set([len(word) for word in word_list])
word_lengths = {n: [word for word in word_list if len(word) == n] 
                   for n in possible_lengths}
```

The above code outputs the following on my machine:

```
>>> print(word_lengths)
{1: ['D'], 3: ['sam', 'Kay', 'Jim'], 4: ['Tuan', 'Anna'], 5: ['Amber', 'Carol', 'Wayne'], 6: ['Steven'], 7: ['Michael', 'Belinda'], 9: ['CharlieYu']}
```

---

Note that this solution is `O(n^2)` complexity. Look into the [`collections`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html) library, which almost certainly has some clever things in it you can do to get a faster solution.